# How to install git to red hat enterprise linux 5.3 x64?

Tags: redhat, yum, git

How can I configure yum to use some repository which has git rpms?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository. The easiest way to enable it is by installing the `epel-release` package. Here's how if you have RHEL 5 x86_64:

```
[root@localhost]# rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-5.noarch.rpm
[root@localhost]# yum install git
```

Comment: I would make sure to install a 64-bit version of git if you're really using a 64-bit system because git is a heavy user of mmap() and loves to have a large address space if the project's getting bigger (during repacking, etc).

Comment: Following Cristian's directions, he will get 64-bit if he is on 64-bit architecture.

Comment: If I run `$ rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm` I get `error: skipping http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error
warning: u 0x1db4cfe0 ctrl 0x1db501a0 nrefs != 0 (download.fedoraproject.org http)`

Comment: @highBandWidth: your mirror might have some issues. Try to download `epel-release` manually by following the instructions from the EPEL page.

Comment: It seems now you need to do `dl.fedoraproject.org`.

Comment: I've heard that the `rpm` command from RHEL5 doesn't know about http redirects (to mirrors), so you should use either the direct download link (`dl.fed...`) or download the RPM file using another program, e.g. wget, curl, etc. and then install it.

Comment: It's not resolving dependencies automatically, i am seeing this error *Missing Dependency: perl(Git) is needed by package git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)*

Comment: @IshKumar: maybe your mirror is not up to date, so wait a couple of days and try again. Or report the issue as recommended [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_help_or_report_issues.3F).

Answer (score 5):

For a more up-to-date version of Git (1.7.2.3 at the time of this writing versus 1.5.5.6 in the EPEL repository), see Andrew Thompson's Webtatic repository:

<strike>http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2009/09/git-on-centos-5/</strike>

Answer (score 0):

i Suggest you can download the source from offical webpage and to do configure & make & make install instead of use yum. :D

Comment: Why?  People like the tracking features of using an RPM, is there some other benefit of compiling yourself?

Comment: Because (make, make install) is the same for every linux System, while the RPMs aren't and have to be changed for every distribution (rhel, ubuntut ....)

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating @Cristian Ciupitu answer it would be possible to do it via yum.repos.d:

1. Go to https://fedoraproject.org/keys and install the `RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL` public key by downloading its contents into the `RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL` file and running `rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL`.
2. Create a file `rhel-epel.repo` (choose any name you want) in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`
3. Add following content:

   ```
   [rhel-epel]
   name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
   baseurl=http://download3.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/$releasever/$basearch
   enabled=1
   gpgcheck=1
   gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL
   ```
4. run `yum install git`.

Answer (score -3):

one way i feel it should work /etc/yum.repos.d/same.repo if you give git locate where your looking git packages

Comment: This doesn't actually lead to a solution.

Comment: Given its score, perhaps this answer should be deleted.

Comment: Better to leave it here to show that it's not a good idea.