# how to install git on CENTOS 5.5

Tags: linux, centos, git, centos5

How can I install git on CENTOS 5.5 machine?
I tried to install it from yum but got following msg.

```
root@host [~]# sudo yum install git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * base: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
 * extras: mirrors.serveraxis.net
 * updates: pubmirrors.reflected.net
addons                                                   |  951 B     00:00
base                                                     | 2.1 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package git available.
Nothing to do
root@host [~]#
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to install git to red hat enterprise linux 5.3 x64?](http://serverfault.com/questions/81362/how-to-install-git-to-red-hat-enterprise-linux-5-3-x64).

Answer (score 4):

Add the EPEL repository and then run 'yum install git' again

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository.3F

Comment: I added epcl respo and tried to install git, but I got errors regarding git Dependencies and unable to install it.

Comment: What dependencies was it not able to find? Post your output here and I'll try to help you get it resolved.

Comment: Is this still the correct way to do this - on a CentOS 5.7 box, tried the RHEL5 option but getting missing dependancies, like perl-Git?

Answer (score 0):

Try download [this](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/12799290/dir/centos_5/com/git-1.6.2.2-1.el5.kb.i386.rpm.html) rpm. Or enable "testing" tag in /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

Comment: actually I am learning linux and new with it so isn't there any easy solution?

Comment: Trying to resolve problems like these are also part of learning. So dont think this situation as a hinderance, rather take this as an opportunity to learn.